# Excel VBA - Nested Do While Loop Not Incrementing

Tags: excel, vba

I have nested "Do While" loops near the bottom of the below code that are not incrementing.  I have stepped through the code, and confirmed that once a non-zero value is found in cell E37 of the "Outages" tab, the code continuously finds a solution for that value instead of incrementing the company code.  The company and trading partner numbers are in a matrix from B2:AE31.  This is an accounting application to figure out which intercompany accounts do not balance by company and trading partner.  Basically, this macro needs to loop through all combination of values for company code and trading partner (1:27 for each).  Any help you can give would be appreciated.

```
'4 - Identify outages in table (loop through)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim CO As String
Dim TP As String
Dim MO As Integer
Dim SolverValue As Double

i = 1 'Company code
j = 1 'Trading partner
MO = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B1").Value2

Do While i < 28
    Range("E34").Value2 = i
    j = 1

    Do While j < 28
    Range("E35").Value2 = j
    Sheets("Outages").Select
    If Range("E37").Value2 <> 0 Then
        CO = Range("E34").Value2
        TP = Range("E35").Value2

    '4a - Run solver for companies if an outage is found
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Solver"

    Sheets("Transactions").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$10000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=MO
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$10000").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=CO, _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=TP
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$10000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=CO, _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=TP
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$10000").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="1"
    Sheets("Transactions").Select
    Rows("1:10000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Solver").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("Q1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+SUM(R[1]C:R[201]C)"
    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+RC[-3]*RC[-1]"
    Range("Q2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Q3:Q203").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("P2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P3:P203").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
    Sheets("Outages").Select
    Range("E37").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Solver").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Style = "Comma"

    SolverReset
    SolverValue = Sheets("Outages").Range("E37")
        SolverOk SetCell:="$Q$1", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=SolverValue, ByChange:= _
        "$P$2:$P$201", Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$P$2:$P$201", Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverSolve True
    Columns("P:R").Select
    Columns("P:R").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    '4b - Copy entries causing outages to a list
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$201").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="1.00"
    Range("A2:Q1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Transactions Causing Outages").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("N:Q").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    '4c - Delete Solver tab
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Solver").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Worksheets("Transactions").ShowAllData  'Unfilter the transactions tab

    End If

    j = j + 1

    Loop

i = i + 1

Loop
```

Comment: You can set a break point at the line `i = 1` then single step through the code to find code that is not behaving as expected.

Comment: I did that, and "j = j +1" is not behaving as expected.  After the code has found a value in cell E37 that is not zero and then processed the outage, the value in cell E35 does not increment to a greater value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheets("Outages").Select was out of place.